# What does the `.<T>` mean in `Array.<T>`?

Tags: documentation, jsdoc

My jsDocs autocompleted to this:

```
/**
 * @returns {Array.<T>}
 */
```

What does the `.<T>` mean in this context, and is there a set of other values it could be?

Comment: Can you show the method that goes along with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means an array of T's (where T is some type or class).

Comment: Isn't that expressed by eg: `@type {String[]}` for an array of Strings?